# How to load module with same name as other module in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Let me explain problem - we have such project:

```
model/__init__.py
model/abstract.py
task/__init__.py
task/model.py
```

How to load into `task/model.py` `model.abstract` what is the syntax for it?

```py
# task/model.py 
import model # it loads task/model.py not model
from model.abstract import test # there is no test exception
```

```py
# model/abstract.py
test = 1
```

How to do such import?

---

Requested more details.

Google App Engine application:
- main is main.py

Directory structure:

```
└───src
    │   app.yaml
    │   index.yaml
    │   main.html
    │   main.py
    │   task_master_api.py
    │
    ├───circle
    │       model.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───model
    │       abstract.py
    │       xxx.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───task
    │       model.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───user
    │       model.py
    │       __init__.py
```

Exception (see task.model not model in root):

```
from .. import model     
logging.critical((type(model), model.__name__))

from model.abstract import AbstractNamed, AbstractForgetable
```

-

```
CRITICAL 2014-02-17 21:23:36,828 model.py:8] (<type 'module'>, 'task.model')

    from model.abstract import AbstractNamed, AbstractForgetable

ImportError: No module named abstract
```

---

Much more related to answer.

```
from .. import model
```

Gives exception.

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Comment: Are you running `model.py` as a script?

Comment: Not - `model.py` is import into another module with `main`.

Answer (score 0):

While the relative imports in ndpu's answer should work, the answer to this question that is burning in my mind is simply this: **change the name of your files to avoid this error**.

If you have `model.py` inside the circle directory, how about changing the name to `circle_model.py`?

Then, you should be able to import modules without any of the relative import `..` business.

**Edit - knowing now that you don't want to rename**

Make sure you have an `__init__.py` file in your src directory, then try the relative import `from .model.abstract import test`

Comment: I know workaround but want to know how to not use workaround.

Comment: Tried `__init__.py` in `src` with `.` = no module with `..` = `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

Answer (score 0):

Relative import given in the other answer should just work fine. But it is not working because you have a name conflict. You have both a package and module named model. try to use another name either for your package or module.

Comment: Is it limitation of python that you can not use module with `name` in module with `name` - is it really exists?

Answer (score 0):

I found two tricks to force load modele `name` into module `name`:

First forcing only absolute loading:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import name
```

Second is like previous but more code and more local impact:

```
save_path = sys.path[:]
sys.path.remove('')
import name
sys.path = save_path
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions all helping people!